# jquery hover problem

Tags: jquery, css, hover

this is the code

```
        //show delete link on hover
    $('li.dir, li.file').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
          if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this ).find("span.delete_file").delay(800).fadeIn('fast');
          }
           else{
            $(this).find("span.delete_file").fadeOut('fast');
          }
    });
```

HTML

```
                <li class="dir" title="">
                    <span class="pin"></span>
                    <span  class="name">test</span> 
                    <span class="delete_file" title="/test"></span>
                        <ul class="sub_folder">
                        </ul>

                </li>
```

CSS

```
ul.sub_folder{
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

    ul.sub_folder > li{
        margin:0;
        line-height: 20px;
        cursor:pointer;
        display:block;
    }
    ul.sub_folder > li:hover{
        background:eee;
    }
        ul.sub_folder > li.file {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        ul.sub_folder > li.file > span.name{
            background:url("/site_images/file.png") left no-repeat;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        ul.sub_folder > li.dir > span.name{
            margin-left:5px;
            background:url("/site_images/folder.png") left no-repeat;
            padding-left: 20px;     
        }

        ul.sub_folder > li.file > span.delete_file{
            background:url("/site_images/cancel.png") left no-repeat;
            padding-left: 20px;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }

        ul.sub_folder > li.dir > span.delete_file{
            margin-left:5px;
            background:url("/site_images/cancel.png") left no-repeat;
            padding-left: 20px;

        }

            ul.sub_folder > li.dir > span.pin{
            background:url("/site_images/folder_arrow.png") left no-repeat;
            width:10px;
            height: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            z-index: 1;
            }
```

I basically wanna show the .delete_file span only when you're on the correspondent `<li>` the problem is that when I pass over the other spans (in the li) the mouse is counted as not "on the li" so the span.delete_file fades out and fades in continuously, for the same reason it disappears ALSO directly on span.delete_file so I can't click on it.
I know it has to with CSS but I can't think of anything, I'm still over the li so why is it considered I'm not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on to what Marlin has said, you can try using `.delegate()` instead.

```
$('ul').delegate('li.dir, li.file', {
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('span.delete_file').stop(true,true).delay(800).fadeIn('fast');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('span.delete_file').stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

The reason why `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` is recommended is because the former event fires when you enter the boundary of the selected element, while the latter fires when you enter the child of the selected element, too (multiple triggers). There is a [good demo](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover#entry-examples) on jQuery API to illustrate this difference.

I also recommend using `.stop(true, true)` to stop the `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` animation queue, or else when a user enters and leaves the selected element in rapid succession, he/she will cause the animation queue to build up (flickering of the `<span class="delete_file'></span>` element).

I've made a short demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QGqmD/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your listeners.  'mouseover' and 'mouseout' bubble anytime a child element is hovered over so your fadeIn method keeps getting called.  Change those to 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'

The Demo on this jquery documentation page depicts exactly what is happening to you.
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

I would also suggest using .delegate() instead of .live() and 'hover' instead of a list of events